# Retrieving values from a created type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

If I create a type, for example `type SchoolClass = (Int,Char)` , how can I retrieve just the Int from a SchoolClass variable? I could create a function that takes a SchoolClass variable as an argument, however, is there a simple solution to this built into Haskell already? Sorry if it's a simple question, I couldn't find the right search terms to get an answer and I am really new to Haskell.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type synonyms (such as `SchoolClass`) behave **exactly** like the types that they represent, so it's simple:

```
getIntFromClass :: SchoolClass -> Int
getIntFromClass (i, _) = i
```

This is actually the same as the `fst` function, which has type `(a,b) -> a`, ie it gets the first member of a 2-tuple. So you could just write:

```
getIntFromClass = fst
```

If you need help with `data` and `type`, read the [LYAH chapter on the subject](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses).